# Почему не происходит запись в конец списка

Tags: c++, c

Есть самописный односвязный список. Хранит данные и указатель на следующий элемент.

```
void insert(List **begin, List * newinsert)//передаем указатель на начало и элемент который нужно вставить
{
    List * insert = newinsert;//записываем данные которые будем вставлять

    if(*begin == NULL)//если список пустой, вставляем все данные в начало. тут всё работает как надо.
    {
        *begin = insert;
        (*begin)->next = NULL;

        return;
    }

    List * temp = *begin;//если список не пустой, запишем указатель на начало в временной переменную

    while(temp) {//пока переменная не равна нулю, переходим к следующему элементу
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    if(!temp) {//когда переменная всё же ноль, я хочу записать в неё данные
        temp = insert;
        temp->next = NULL;
    }

}
```

Но вот в этом случае ничего не работает. При выводе на консоль, выводится только первый элемент. В чем может быть ошибка. Вроди всё должно быть просто, но не срослось.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что переменная `temp` принимает значение `null` и потом происходит запись нового элемента во временную переменную.

Попробуйте так:

```
List* current = *begin;
while (current) {
    if (current->next) {
        // Не достигли конца списка.
        current = current->next;
    } else {
        // Конец списка, вставляем элемент.
        current->next = insert;
        insert->next = NULL;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо. понял.

Answer (score 1):

Это происходит потому, что на ваш элемент никто не ссылается. Нужно сделать так, чтобы `next` последнего элемента указывал на  ваш новый элемент.